# Java Swing: Waiting for Mouse Clicked event before returning an Int

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, wait

I have a card game and which is built on using ArrayLists to store the cards in peoples hands. I have a main method which plays through the game and updates the GUI class using threads called using InvokeLater in the main class

At the moment I'm playing the game on the console and inputting and int into a scanner to make the selection of card from the players hand. What I want to do is to run a thread, probably with invoke and wait, that runs when the player has to make a selection. Then waits for the player to click on the corresponding card in the GUI and return the appropriate int of the place of the card. This selection is then handled by my game.

How I'm updating my GUI at the moment.

```
      public static void Play(ArrayList<Card> ...){
        UpdateHand(player1, deck, deckused);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                GUI.getInstance().UpdateHand();

            }
        });
```

Attaching listeners to cards and setting their names to the int of their corresponding place in the hand.

```
   public void PlayerSelection()
    {
        selection = -1;
        Information = new JLabel("Please Select Your Card");
        ButtonDisplay.add(Information);
        ButtonDisplay.updateUI();
        for (int i = 0; i < (HumanHand.size()); i++)
           {
               Card card = HumanHand.get(i);

               BufferedImage cardImage = null;

                try {

                    cardImage = ImageIO.read(new File("card/" + card + ".jpg"));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( cardImage ));
                    String name = "" + i;
                    picLabel.setName(name);
                    picLabel.addMouseListener((MouseListener) this);
                    HumanHandDisplay.add(picLabel);
           }
    }
```

storing the int for selection when the mouse is clicked.

```
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        String name = ((JLabel)e.getSource()).getName();
        System.out.println("Working " + name);
        selection = Integer.parseInt(name);         
    }
```

I want to return this int to my main class Play() method for use in the rest of the computation. I can't work out how to do this, specifically waiting for the selection to be made. I've heard that this can be done but I'm unsure as to how to implement this in my work. If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't want to pause threads or any of that sort here. Instead you'll change the state of your program depending on where in the program the user is, and depending on his responses and the behavior of the program will vary depending on that state.

For instance, if the user needs to wait for a user to play a card, you give the main class a currentPlayer variable, and assign it to the user when its his turn. Then code the program so that it doesn't respond to any user input except for valid input that is appropriate for his turn.

Then the main GameEngine class will advance the currentPlayer variable to the next player and await their responses.

**Edit 1**
You state:

> I'm not sure I really understand. I've already implemented the game and all it's rules and AI players to play against, which I do on the console for now. I just need to extend where I'm making selections using a scanner out on to the GUI to wait for a Mouse Clicked event.

Please understand that you're making a large transition, moving from a console based linear program to a GUI *event*-based program, the key being that the new program is event-based. If your current code is written with well-behaved OOPs-compliant classes, with minimal static variables and methods, and with classes that have well-defined states, then the transition should go smoothly. If on the other hand your current code base has only few classes, most centered around the linear console user interface,  you may need to re-write your code from scratch.

You may wish to show us some of your current code and describe its design.

Next you state:

> How would I go about makeing sure that the program doesn't respond to anything other than an int?

Please clarify what you mean by having the program only respond to an int. An int where? in a JTextField? Somewhere else? This may likely require some type of input validation, I think.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand. I've already implemented the game and all it's rules and AI players to play against, which I do on the console for now. I just need to extend where I'm making selections using a scanner out on to the GUI to wait for a Mouse Clicked event.

How would I go about makeing sure that the program doesn't respond to anything other than an int?

Comment: @Sean: please see **Edit 1**.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is modality on a custom component and that is not possible in Swing (at least not without A LOT of effort implementing your own modality). Your program should have states and be event-based, just like @Hovercraft's answer.